# Replacing Value of Input based off of the sun of two inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to add up the sum of two inputs that already have a value in it. I wanted the sum to change value if any of the other two inputs change in value. I have this the following, but its not working:

```
<?php


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($test)) {
echo "<tr class='saved_add'>";
echo "<td><input/></td>";
echo "<td><input/></td>";

echo "<td><select'>";
echo "<option value='service'";
if ($row['type'] == "service") {
echo "selected='selected'";}
echo ">Service</option>";
echo "<option value='hours'";
if ($row['type'] == "hours") {
echo "selected='selected'";}
echo ">Hours</option>";
echo "<option value='days'";
if ($row['type'] == "days") {
echo "selected='selected'";}
echo ">Days</option>";
echo "<option value='product'";
if ($row['type'] == "product") {
echo "selected='selected'";}
echo ">Product</option></select></td>";

echo "<td><input/></td>";
echo "<td><input/></td>";
echo "<td><input/></td>";
echo "<td><input/></td>";
echo "<td><input class='subtotal'/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.saved_add').each(function() {
   sum = $('input:eq(2)', this).val() * $('input:eq(5)', this).val();
    $(".subtotal").text(sum);
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: Just an idea...open a debugger and debug it. Do the jquery selectors resolve to the correct elements? Are you having casting issues on sum? Is the code even being executed?

Comment: Thats the thing @malk it doesnt show any errors

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
function calculateSum() {
  $('.saved_add').each(function() {
    sum = $('input:eq(2)', this).val() * $('input:eq(5)', this).val();
    $(".subtotal").text(sum);
    });
  }

// On first load
calculateSum();

// On change
$("input").change(calculateSum);
```

Your code will only calculate the value WHEN IT LOADS. You want to calculate it when it loads AND when the value changes, so you need the `.change()` function.

Comment: Thanks for answering Francisco but the each statement is for each <tr class=save_add> so $("input:eq(2), input:eq(5)").change(calculateSum); wont work.

Comment: I didn't see the html code you added. However the point is still valid, you need to update it when the input changes (edited to show a generic way)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.val()` on an element it returns its value as a string. You have to convert it to a number first before you can do mathematical operations with it. To convert strings to integers, you can use the `parseInt()` method.

```
$('.saved_add').each(function() {
  var sum = $('input:eq(2)', this).val() * $('input:eq(5)', this).val();
  $(".subtotal").text(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try

```
$('.saved_add').each(function(i, el) {   
    $(el).on("change", function() {
       // cast `sum` as `Number`
       sum = Number($('input:eq(2)', this).val() * $('input:eq(5)', this).val());
    $(".subtotal").text(sum);
}).change();
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/20jeoc9y/

Comment: This wont work either because there is no each statement. I need to have an each statement because inputs are dynamically being created.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but that work work for more than one input.

Comment: "that work work for more than one input." ? Piece at post / jsfiddle return product of 2 elements provided at OP. If possible , please describe issue of piece at post , specific details of requirement ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping, i figured it out. Helps out to make each input as an ID so you can change it accordingly.

HTML:

```
<div id="saved1">
    <input type="text" value="10" /><input type="text" value="10" /> <input type="text" value="10" />     
    <div id="subtotal1"></div>
</div>
<div id="saved2">
    <input type="text" value="10" /><input type="text" value="10" /> <input type="text" value="10" />     
    <div id="subtotal2"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
function calculateSum() {
  $("[id^=saved]").each(function() {
    sum = $('input:eq(0)', this).val() * $('input:eq(1)', this).val();
    $('input:eq(2)', this).val(sum);
    });
  }

// On first load
calculateSum();

// On change
$("input").change(calculateSum);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18muxa2s/1/)